# Node name as parameter

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi my xml looks like this

```
<Component name="super.useful.component">
      <StringValue name="component.title.1">
               <Value>some value</Value>
      </StringValue>
      <StringValue name="component.title.2">
               <Value>some more value</Value>
      </StringValue>
</Component>
```

all i want to do is to have the name as parameter.

My xsl looks like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="showComponents">
                <xsl:with-param name="container" select="//Component/StringValue[@name????]/> 
            </xsl:call-template
```

so when i call it , it can have the both names of the components.

```
<xsl:template name="showComponents">
        <xsl:param name="container" />
        <xsl:for-each select="Component[@name='$container']>    

        //do stuff here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are fumbling upon the xpath to get the attribute `name`for `StringValue` elements. If that is the case, the xpath selector will be :

`//StringValue/@name`

Comment: Wow , it was so easy , thanks. 12 hours to work and on

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you got part of your answer already from @svasa, but **also note** that you almost certainly not what you want

```
    <xsl:for-each select="Component[@name='$container']>
```

but rather

```
    <xsl:for-each select="Component[@name=$container]>
```

otherwise you'll be testing literally against the string, `'$container'`, without variable evaluation.

Comment: Yeah good point , i tried it to my Program with the ' ' at first and it didn't work , then without and all good.